# Extending multiple entities IN TypeORM-NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Hi I don't wanted to keep adding common columns to all entity. So I'm thinking to write it on separate class and extend it to those which needs those columns.
I Tried something but it is throwing " Classes can only extend a single class" Error

I don't have much hands on on TS, I'm new to TS.
Can anyone help me out ?

Please find the below code:

1.Base Entity

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class BaseModel {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;
}
```

2. Audit Entity

```
import { CreateDateColumn, DeleteDateColumn, Entity, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class AuditModel {
    @CreateDateColumn()
    created!: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated!: Date;

    @DeleteDateColumn()
    deletedAt?: Date;
}
```

3.User Entity

```
import { AuditModel } from 'src/baseModels/auditEntity';
import { BaseModel } from 'src/baseModels/baseEntity';
import {
  Entity,
  Column
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Users extends BaseModel,AuditModel {

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({default:false})
  isActive:boolean

  @Column({ select: false })
  password: string;

}
```

Comment: Your BaseModel and AuditModel shouldn't even be entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other languages, JavaScript does not allow you to extend more than one class (single inheritance).

I would suggest making your AuditModel extend BaseModel:

```
export class AuditModel extends BaseModel {
    @CreateDateColumn()
    created!: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated!: Date;

    @DeleteDateColumn()
    deletedAt?: Date;
}
```

Then your UsersModel only has to extend the AuditModel:

```
@Entity()
export class Users extends AuditModel {

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({default:false})
  isActive:boolean

  @Column({ select: false })
  password: string;

}
```

---

**Do not use @Entity on classes that won't live in your database!**

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation in Typescript. You **cannot** extend more than one class, for the main reason of if you call `super.property` which `super` are you calling to? You could create some sort of mixin that could take any number of classes and apply them to the prototype of the class you're currently building, but that may end up being needlessly complex for little gain